# Rearrange rows according to common column element

Tags: matlab

Give for example the matrices

```
A = [20 1  2  3;
     3  3  3  4];

B = [3  3  3  3;
     20 1  2  4];
```

Each column of matrix `A` has a common element. Is it possible without for loops to rearrange rows of `A` so as the common element to be in the top or bottom row (see matrix `B`)?

Comment: Is there an external way to tell what the common element is? Also, can other numbers be repeated? So would this be a valid `A`: `A =  [20 1  2  3; 3  3  3  1];`? Is `A` always only 2 rows?

Comment: Why won't you a loop ? sometime the faster way to do an operation is to use some loops. Of course you can "hide" your loop with some pre-built function like `arrayfun` but in fact it's a loop.

Comment: @Dan Number 2 is not always the common element, and yes there are only two rows.

Comment: so you should have a look at the function `intersect`

Comment: @Thoth " Number 2 is not always the common element" Sorry I don't know what that means. My question was can any other number be repeated in addition to the common element. If you look at my example `A` you will see that `3` is the common element however the number `1` is in two columns as well. Is that allowed or not? It makes a big difference to the complexity of the problem.

Comment: @Dan The common element is the one that repeated in all columns. Thanks for the interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use the [Set functions with multiple inputs](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28341-set-functions-with-multiple-inputs) file exchange submission by Oleg to find the common element. First convert `A` to a cell array of column vectors using `mat2cell`. Then break it up into a comma separated list using the `{:}` notation to feed each column to `intersectm` (from the FEX entry linked to above) as separate inputs

```
A_cell = mat2cell(A,2,ones(1,size(A,2)));
common = intersectm(A_cell{:});
```

now find which row the common element lies in per column and use linear indexing to flip the columns in which the common element is in the second row

```
[r, c] = find(A == common);
idx_r = (r+c*2-2)';
idx = idx_r;
idx(2,:) = (idx_r-1).*~mod(idx_r,2) + (idx_r+1).*mod(idx_r,2);
```

Finally

```
B = A(idx)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. With all respect, according to @obchardon `intersect` can give the result partially, `[3  3  3  4;20  1  2  3]`. This means that the column where the common element is in first row is flipped too, something we do not want. Can you hive a hint on this, so as to have an answer using only `build-in` matlab functions?

Comment: @Thoth not until you answer the very simple question I asked twice already. CAN OTHER NUMBERS ASIDE FROM THE COMMON ELEMENT BE REPEATED? If they can't then you can find the common element by just calling intersect on the first two columns and then use the rest of my code. If they can then just use my answer, your requirement to use built-in MATLAB makes no sense. The code from the FEX is **free** and based entirely on built-in MATLAB and completely open source meaning once you have downloaded the 5 text files it's just part of your project as if you had written it yourself.